# What is the inverse limit of algebraic stacks?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-stacks

Let $S$ be a base scheme. Let $(F_{i},f_{ii'})_{i\in I}$ be a directed inverse system of algebraic spaces over $S$. Then if each $f_{ii'}$ is affine, the inverse limit $\lim_{i}F_{i}$ exists as an algebraic space.

Let $({\cal{X}}_{i},g_{ii'})_{i\in I}$ be a directed inverse system of algebraic stacks over $S$. Then as the case of algebraic spaces, is the inverse limit $\lim_{i}\cal{X}_{i}$ exists as an algebraic stack? If not, when $\lim_{i}\cal{X}_{i}$ is an algebraic stack? In fact, it seems that there is no reference concerning the inverse limit $\lim_{i}\cal{X}_{i}$ of algebraic stacks. I have no idea what is the definition of the limit $\lim_{i}\cal{X}_{i}$. Is it simply a small limit in $Cat$?

This is what I found in Xinwen Zhu's paper (arXiv:1707.05700v1).
[image]

Comment: You should share your thoughts and motivation. I know nothing about this subject but I think it is possible that, in case your limit object isn’t well behaved, you’ll still be able to get something useful out of your object. Questions like “when is […]” are helped by motivating contexts (to get sufficient, though maybe not necessary, conditions)

Comment: I have editted my question more clearly.